Regarding set definition in Theorem 3.22 in Folland's Real analysis
I feel silly for asking for such a small remark in the proof, but yet I have not been able to understand why for some time now. I have a question concerning Theorem 3.22 in Folland's real analysis textbook. A full proof can be found here, but I don't think this is needed as my question is simply about a definition of a set. Here's the relevant extract.

Why is an $x\in F_k$ the center of a ball $B_x$ such that $\lambda(B_x)>k^{-1}m(B_x)$? The definition of $F_k$ is: $$x\in F_k\implies\limsup_{r\to0}\frac{\lambda (B(r,x))}{m(B(r,x))}>\frac1{k}.$$Why would $\lambda(B_x)>k^{-1}m(B_x)$ be true?

By definition of $F_k$: $\limsup_{r\to0}\frac{\lambda (B(r,x))}{m(B(r,x))}>\frac1{k} $ implies that $\frac{\lambda (B(r,x))}{m(B(r,x))}>\frac1{k}$ for some $r>0$.

Thank you, now I get it!

As claimed in the comments, $\limsup_{r\to0}\frac{\lambda (B(r,x))}{m(B(r,x))}>\frac1{k}$ implies there is an $r'>0$ such that $\frac{\lambda (B(r',x))}{m(B(r',x))}>\frac1{k}$. If no such $r'$ existed, then $\frac{\lambda (B(r',x))}{m(B(r',x))}\leq \frac1{k}$ for all $r>0$. Since $\limsup$ respects inequalities, we'd have $\limsup_{r\to0} \frac{\lambda (B(r',x))}{m(B(r',x))}\leq \frac1{k}$. This is a contradiction.
